# xterm not opening inside Mininet hosts. NO SSH, NO VM

Tags: ubuntu, xterm, mininet

I just installed **Ubuntu** 17.10, and **Mininet** 2.2.2 from Packages (`sudo apt-get install mininet`) on my laptop. Natively, i.e. a real OS on a real machine, **no virtual machines of any sort**. The laptop is a 2017 MacBook Pro 13" without touchbar (MacBookPro14,1), and Ubuntu runs on a fast USB key; just writing for completeness, I don't think it's relevant.

I need CLI access to each Mininet host that I'm going to create, in order to run custom tests and observe the traffic that passes by in each node.

On my former laptop, I had a similar setup but with older versions of Ubuntu and probably also Mininet, and I managed to be able to spawn `xterm`s from every Mininet host that I wanted. The problem is, I don't remember at all how I did it =).

`echo $DISPLAY` returns `:0` whether I run it in a regular shell or in a Mininet host, but in a regular shell `xterm` opens an xterm window. Let's say `h1` is my Mininet host. I start Mininet with `sudo mn` and I get:

- `h1 echo $DISPLAY` --> `:0`
- `xterm h1` --> nothing, and nothing happens
- `h1 xterm &` --> nothing, and nothing happens
- `h1 xterm` --> `No protocol specified. Warning: This program is an suid-root program or is being run by the root user. The full text    of the error or warning message cannot be safely formatted in this    environment. You may get a more descriptive message by running the    program as a non-root user or by removing the suid bit on the    executable. xterm: Xt error: Can't open display: %s`

All info that I could find is related to X11 forwarding with ssh, and everything I've tried failed.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `xhost +local:` in a terminal without being superuser to fix the issue. Below the details.

---

The issue is due to xterm not working by default when authenticated as superuser (Mininet has to be run as superuser), for security reasons.

You can check if this is your issue by running `xterm` and `sudo xterm` in a terminal when being logged in as usual (if you did something like `sudo su` before this check is pointless).
If `xterm` opens, but `sudo xterm` doesn't, then you need to run

```
xhost +local:
```

`sudo xterm` should work now, as well as `h1 xterm` inside Mininet.
This is because with that command you provided graphical server access to applications running as `sudo` or `su`.

The setting won't persist between reboots, and it can be reverted with `xhost -`.

Please note that by doing this, you are giving any user on the system or the network access to your $DISPLAY without authentication (https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Xhost).